# Exclude a WordPress custom taxonomy term from query_posts()

Tags: php, wordpress, query-string, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I've added the following code on one of my archive pages, just before the loop. I need this particular archive to display in alphabetical order, rather than chronological. This does what it's supposed to do.

```
global $query_string;
$posts = query_posts($query_string . '&orderby=title&order=asc&posts_per_page=-1');
```

I *also* need it to exclude a particular taxonomy term. My taxonomy is called "company-type," and I want it to exclude the term "featured." I'm able to filter it to show ONLY that taxonomy term by adding `&company-type=featured`, but I need to accomplish the opposite.

Everything I've found that purports to accomplish this uses a very different syntax. I tried to match my current arguments to that syntax, but no luck, and I can't figure out how it would fit into this example. The examples I've seen use the `tax_query` parameter, but I can't get it to work with my code.

I know there are likely multiple ways to accomplish this, and I've read that using `query_posts` isn't necessarily the best solution, but it's the only one I've gotten to work so far. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Check this [question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12217/how-do-i-exclude-a-custom-taxonomy-from-the-post-loop). This will help you.

Comment: Thanks, @Gunaseelan. I did see that post in my initial search, and I tried to implement the rest of my code using that format, but I wasn't able to get it working.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I got it working. I used a different syntax, which I had tried several times, but it hadn't been working for me because I didn't know how to include the original arguments from my `$query_string` with it.

There's a WordPress function called `wp_parse_args` that will get them into the same format for you. This is the code I ended up with. (I also switched to `WP_Query` instead of `query_posts`, now that I understand why it wasn't working for me before.)

```
global $query_string;

$args = array( 
  'tax_query' =>  array (
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'company-type', // My Custom Taxonomy
      'terms' => 'featured', // My Taxonomy Term that I wanted to exclude
      'field' => 'slug', // Whether I am passing term Slug or term ID
      'operator' => 'NOT IN', // Selection operator - use IN to include, NOT IN to exclude
    ),
  ),
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'orderby' => 'title',
  'order'=>'ASC'
);

$args = wp_parse_args( $query_string, $args );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Good that you switched to `WP_Query`, `query_posts()` is just a horrible way to perform custom queries and should **NEVER EVER** be used